# Does the expansion of space imply an increase in the dimensional volume of objects?

Tags: expansion

Does the expansion of space only occur in the space between celestial objects or is it effecting the dimensional volume of the objects themselves? In simple terms is my ruler expanding due to the expansion of the universe?

Comment: Well the conservation of mass should show that an expanding universe of constant mass should decrease in density over time. Do you mean planets and stars? I suppose it depends, because some celestial bodies will collide to form larger bodies. Not sure this fully answers the question, but it’s a place to start.